# Can I USB-tether my Android tablet to my Android phone?

Tags: usb-tethering

Is it possible to USB-tether my WiFi-only Galaxy Tab to my Galaxy S?

I know how to WiFi tether but it is a huge battery hog. Is there a mini-USB version of the Galaxy Tab cable? If so, can it be used to tether?

Comment: I highly doubt it, the wifi access point mode that android has built is what everyone uses.

Comment: That's a shame because I use USB tethering with my laptop and it's faster and uses less battery.

Comment: I would argue that usb would not noticeably faster, we are talking about 3g data connection yeah? haha But sure you may have a point with battery usage on wifi vs a usb connection, but hey now you dont have to carry around a silly usb cord ;)

Answer (score 2):

There is a bit tricky method suggested by one of the XDA members. Rooting is required.

1. Download & install a Terminal Emulator on your Android tablet.
2. Run the Emulator & enter the following commands:

   ```
   dhcpcd usb1
   setprop net.dns1 8.8.8.8
   ```

The Android phone from which the internet connection is to be sourced must be connected via a USB cable, and then enable USB tethering on that phone.

Now you can access the internet on your Android tablet using your Android phone as a USB modem!

Comment: Only for the sake of completeness: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=16182227&postcount=6 . It seems as if the kernel module *USB_WWAN* must be enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! First, attach an OTG cable to your tablet. Then, attach a MicroUSB and connect both devices. Now download one of the numerous apps which make tethering possible and you're done!

If your devices support Bluetooth tethering, you can use it. It doesn't consume too beach battery also. :)

P.S. isn't creating a WiFi hotspot a better idea?

Comment: This wont work unless the tablet supports USB-OTG, which not all devices do. And depending on the version of the Galaxy S and Galaxy Tab, if they are the "first" versions of those devices, they do not support USB-OTG. - Also the asker says they don't want to use wifi because it drains the battery on their device(s).

Comment: @Ryan Yes but most devices nowadays do

Comment: For completeness of the answer though, not all devices do. Especially the devices listed in the original question.

Comment: Often you download an app on the device that has an Internet connection. What do you do on the tablet? Is it something generic?  @rahulbasu

Answer (score 0):

I did it by connecting an ethernet dongle to each device and an e-cable to the dongles. I imagine it would use less power than wireless, and I can place the hotspot device away for the best reception.