# Share Android cell phone network connection over USB OTG to Wifi Android tablet

Tags: nexus-7, usb-connection-mode, usb-on-the-go, usb-host-mode, samsung-galaxy-s-6

How do I share my cell phone's network connection with a Wifi tablet? Specifically I'm using a Samsung Galaxy S6 and a Nexus 7.

I bought a USB OTG cable. Which end do I plug the USB into, and which end do I plug the micro USB into?

How do I share my cell phone connection with the Nexus 7? I didn't see a USB setting in either direction for sharing the connection.

Is rooting required?

Comment: I don't think most devices support USB internet connections out-of-the-box. Is wireless not an option? You can use most devices as a portable WiFi hotspot, or tether over Bluetooth.

Comment: Sprint makes you pay to enable WiFi hotspots. Apparently the Nexus 7 has many Bluetooth issues that make Bluetooth tethering impossible / very difficult unfortunately

Comment: I used to tether via Bluetooth all the time from a phone to a Nexus 7 without any issue other than the limited bandwidth of Bluetooth.

Comment: I'll retest and post a separate question about BlueTooth tethering. It looked like many people were having the same issue with the 2012 Nexus 7 @TurboFool

Comment: I posted my bluetooth tethering issues as [Can't bluetooth tether between sprint galaxy s6 and nexus 7](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/114791/cant-bluetooth-tether-between-sprint-galaxy-s6-and-nexus-7) Can you take a look? @TurboFool

Answer (score 0):

I would leave a comment but I dont have enough reputation.
I found this [question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/19707/can-i-usb-tether-my-android-tablet-to-my-android-phone) and the first answer maybe shows a possible solution posted on [xda](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=16182227&postcount=6).
For this you need root.

> Download & install a Terminal Emulator on your Android Tablet. Run the Emulator & enter the following commands:
>
> dhcpcd usb1
>
> setprop net.dns1 8.8.8.8
>
> The Android Phone from which net connection is to be sourced must be connected via USB Cable & on that phone enable USB Tether.
>
> Now you can access internet on your Android Tablet using your Android Phone as a USB Modem!

I always use Bluetooth to share internet between phone and tablet. A friend of mine has a Nexus 7 too and no problems with Bluetooth. Maybe you can look for a solution to this issues