# Can't bluetooth tether between sprint galaxy s6 and nexus 7

Tags: nexus-7, tethering, samsung-galaxy-s-6, bluetooth-tethering

On my galaxy s6, I activate the Bluetooth server. I've confirmed that Bluetooth tethering works with my laptop.

On My Nexus 7, the s6 shows up in the paired devices list. I click on settings, and check "use for internet access".

"Connecting..." Flashes, and then goes away. Check box becomes unchecked.

How do I tether my Nexus 7 to my s6?

I'm open to a different app if it will work.

I've read that there are issues withe Bluetooth on the Nexus 7. Could this be the cause?

**edit: I'm using PDANET on my s6 **

Comment: What software are you using for Bluetooth tethering from the S6? I haven't used a Galaxy in years, so I can't speak to this too much...